# Adding a new WP Query inside an ACF block

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to make a block called **Popular Services** using ACF blocks. That will show a grid of the 6 most popular **services**, (image with description in a permalink), from the custom post type I created called **services**.

Here is the CPT in functions.php

```
function services_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'=> 'Services',
    'singular_name' => 'Service',
    'menu_name' => 'Services',
    'name_admin_bar' => 'Services',
    'archives' => 'Service Archives',
    'attributes' => 'Service Attributes',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Services:',
    'all_items' => 'All Services',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add A Service',
    'add_new' => 'Add A Service',
    'new_item' => 'New Service',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit The Service',
    'update_item' => 'Update The Service',
    'view_item' => 'View The Service',
    'view_items' => 'View The Services',
    'search_items' => 'Search The Services',
    'not_found' => 'No Service Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Service Found In Trash',
    'featured_image' => 'Open Graph Image',
    'set_featured_image' => 'Set The Social Sharing Image',
    'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove The Social Sharing Image',
    'use_featured_image' => 'Use As The Social Sharing Image',
    'insert_into_item' => 'Insert Into This service',
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded To This Service',
    'items_list' => 'Service List',
    'items_list_navigation' => 'Service List Navigation',
    'filter_items_list' => 'Filter The Service List',
);
    $args = array(
    'label' => 'Services',
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => 'Services At Biddenden Chiropractic', 
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-list-view',
    'delete_with_user' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
    'show_in_rest' => true
);
register_post_type( 'services', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'services_post_type' );
```

As I'm building a block based theme, On every post, I have an Advanced Custom Field Section for **Search Image** and **Search Description**.

I use these in the PHP templates, such as **front-page.php** to display quick links.

To use this data, I pull through what I need using this method.
**new WP_Query**.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'post_type'         => 'services'
);
$category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if($category_posts->have_posts()) : while($category_posts->have_posts()) : $category_posts->the_post(); { ?>

<!-- The Services Excerpt -->
<?php get_template_part( 'includes-archives/popular', 'services-excerpt' ); ?>

<?php } endwhile; else: { ?>
<h2>There are no posts.</h2>

<?php } endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

with this **Services Excerpt** in my template parts.

```
<?php
    // Variables
    $search_image = get_field( 'search_image' );
    $search_description = get_field( 'search_description' );
    $title = get_the_title();
    $link = get_the_permalink();
?>

<!-- Excerpt Container -->
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
    <!-- Image -->
    <figure>
    <img <?php responsive_acf_square_image( $search_image, 'sm-square', '(min-width: 1500px) 20vw, (min-width: 1300px) 25vw, (min-width: 950px) 33.333vw, (min-width: 650px) 50vw' ); ?>
    </figure>
    <!-- Excerpt Text -->
    <div class="text-content">
        <!-- Title -->
        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <!-- Paragraph Text -->
        <p><?php echo $search_description; ?></p>
    </div>              
</a>
```

Using this method works perfectly on any page or post template.

But not inside an ACF block template.
Then I only get the core Wordpress information to use;

```
the_title();
the_permalink();
```

The block template can't find the;

```
get_field( 'search_image' );
get_field( 'search_description' );
```

data.

Does anyone understand why this won't work within the block.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

```
<?php get_template_part( 'includes-archives/popular', 'services-excerpt' ); ?>
```

I had these variables to bring in the data.

```
<?php
    // Variables
    $search_image = get_field( 'search_image' );
    $search_description = get_field( 'search_description' );
    $title = get_the_title();
    $link = get_the_permalink();
?>
```

And I needed to add **get_the_id** Like so.

```
<?php
    // Variables
    $search_image = get_field( 'search_image', get_the_ID() );
    $search_description = get_field( 'search_description', get_the_ID() );
    $title = get_the_title();
    $link = get_the_permalink();
?>
```

Hope this helps someone else struggling with the same issue.